Du/Sie bei Drittpersonen
Wenn ich mit A. Mustermann per Sie und Nachname bin und mit B. Musterfrau per Vorname und Du, wie referiere ich in dem Fall an B. Musterfrau, wenn ich mit A. Mustermann rede oder schreibe?
Wenn ich bei "Sie" bin, soll ich dann grundsätzliche alle Personen, an denen referiert wird, nur bei Nachnamen erwähnen?

Sehr geehrter Herr Mustermann, Frau Musterfrau hat mir bereits geholfen.  Mit freundlichen Grüßen.

Kommt mir etwas seltsam vor, wenn ich mit B. bei "Du" bin.
Oder kann ich den Kollegen beim Vornamen erwähnen?

Sehr geehrter Herr Mustermann, die B. hat mir bereits geholfen.  Mit freundlichen Grüßen.

Dann gibt es eine Mischung aus formal und informal. Ist das akzeptabel?
Oder beiden?

Sehr geehrter Herr Mustermann, B. Musterfrau hat mir bereits geholfen.  Mit freundlichen Grüßen.

In diesem Beispiel geht es um Schriftverkehr, aber meine Frage bezieht sich sowohl auf schriftliche als auch auf mündliche Kommunikation.  Für diese Frage nehme ich an, dass alle Beteiligten einander beim vollständigen Vor- und Nachname kennen, und bei allen Alternativen eindeutig klar ist, wer gemeint wird.

In manchen Regionen Deutschlands würde "die B." als unhöflich aufgefasst, egal wie die drei beteiligten Personen zueinander stehen und ob sie per Du oder per Sie sind. Der Zwiebelfisch hat das ganz gut beschrieben.

@Raketenolli Danke für den Hinweis.  Davon war ich mir überhaupt nicht bewusst.

Ein konkretes Beispiel: Sabine Kastner ist Inhaberin und Geschäftsführerin eines Unternehmens mit ca. 15 Mitarbeiter*innen. Monika Fuchs ist Kastners Sekretärin, Stefan Fuchs ist Monikas Ehemann und der Logistik-Leiter dieses Unternehmens. Innerhalb dieses Unternehmens sind alle Personen miteinander per Du und sprechen einander mit dem Vornamen an. Ich bin privat mit Monika und Stefan Fuchs befreundet und spreche beide mit »Du« und dem Vornamen an. Frau Kastner spreche ich mit »Sie« und dem Nachnamen an. Otto Krainer ist mein Chef. Niemand aus der Firma von Frau Kastner ist mit ihm per Du, ich hingegen schon.



.
Sabine Kastner
Monika Fuchs
Stefan Fuchs
Otto Krainer
ich




Sabine Kastner

Du
Du
Sie
Sie


Monika Fuchs
Du

Du
Sie
Du


Stefan Fuchs
Du
Du

Sie
Du


Otto Krainer
Sie
Sie
Sie

Du


ich
Sie
Du
Du
Du




Wenn ich mich mit Frau Kastner über andere Personen unterhalte, nenne ich alle Personen immer beim Nachnamen, also auch jene Personen, mit denen ich per Du bin, und von denen ich weiß, dass Frau Kastner sie ebenfalls mit »Du« anspricht.
E-Mail an Frau Kastner:

Sehr geehrte Frau Kastner,
Frau Fuchs hat mir mitgeteilt, dass unser eigentlich für morgen geplantes Meeting auf nächste Freitag verschoben werden muss. Mein Chef, Herr Krainer, hätte da ebenfalls Zeit und würde da gerne mit mir mitkommen. Geht das für Sie in Ordnung?
Mit freundlichen Grüßen
Dipl.-Ing. Hubert Schölnast

Unterhalte ich mich hingegen mit jemandem, mit dem ich per Du bin, nenne ich alle Personen, mit denen ich per Du bin, und von denen ich weiß (oder vermute), dass auch mein Gesprächspartner per Du mit ihnen ist, mit dem Vornamen. Das gilt aber nicht für Personen, von denen ich weiß, dass mein Kommunikationspartner mit ihnen per Sie ist.
E-Mail an Monika Fuchs:

Liebe Monika,
ich habe mit Frau Kastner vereinbart, dass ich nächste Woche meinen Chef, Herrn Krainer, zum Termin mitbringe. Er ist Veganer, und ich vermute, dass es unserem geplantem Projekt hilft, wenn du das bitte beim Catering berücksichtigen könntest. - Danke!
Anderes Thema: Stefan hat mich zu eurem Grill-Abend am Freitag eingeladen, aber ich erreiche ihn gerade nicht. Weist du, ob Frau Kastner da auch dabei sein wird?
Liebe Grüße
Hubert


Noch eine Ergänzung:
Mit jemandem per Vorname zu sein ist nicht dasselbe, wie mit jemandem per Du zu sein. Das korreliert zwar im Normalfall, aber manche Menschen werden - aus unterschiedlichsten Gründen - auch dann mit dem Nachnamen angesprochen, wenn man per Du mit ihnen ist. Ein Beispiel: In den 1990er-Jahren wurde für den ORF die Kult-Fernsehserie Kaisermühlen Blues produziert. Eine der unzähligen Figuren in dieser Serie ist der manchmal grantige aber trotzdem immer liebenswerte Polizist Trautmann, mit dem jeder per Du ist, den aber jeder einfach nur "der Trautmann" nennt. Es gab in den 2000er-Jahren rund um diesen Polizisten sogar eine Spinn-Off-Serie mit dem Namen Trautmann. In der Spinn-Off-Serie (10 Folgen á 90 Minuten) wird zwar mehrmals thematisiert, dass sogar unter den engsten Freund von Trautmann viele sind, die seinen Vornamen nicht kennen, aber Trautmanns Vorname wird in dieser Serie kein einziges Mal verwendet. In der Originalserie (64 Folgen á ca. 50 Minuten) kommt Trautmanns Vorname meines Wissens nur ein einziges Mal vor. In dieser Szene sagt Trautmann, dass er der uneheliche Sohn eines englischen Besatzungssoldaten ist und lieber mit seinem Nachnamen angesprochen werden will, weil ihm sein Vorname Polycarp peinlich ist.
Ich kenne übrigens auch eine Frau in Wien (eine ehemalige Arbeitskollegin), die ihren Langzeit-Lebensgefährten immer "der Gassner" nennt. Sogar als der Gassner mal bei einer Feier anwesend war, habe ich mitbekommen, das meine Arbeitskollegin ihn nicht beim Vornamen nannte, sonder auch im direkten Gespräch beim Nachnamen (»He, Gassner!« (Sie winkt ihn herbei.) »Komm mal her, Gassner. Kennst du eigentlich die Miriam schon? Miriam, das ist der Gassner, mein Lebensgefährte; Gassner, das ist die Miriam, meine neue Arbeitskollegin.«)
Und auch ich war in der Volksschule (österreichisches Gegenstück zur Grundschule in Deutschland) für meine Mitschüler immer "der Schölli" (kurz für Schölnast), obwohl wir Kinder untereinander natürlich alle per Du waren. Das lag daran, dass ein Mitschüler aus meiner Klasse ebenfalls Hubert hieß, und so Verwechslungen vermieden wurden. Der andere Hubert wurde übrigens konsequenterweise "der Gruber" genannt.

Danke für die sehr ausführliche Antwort und die Ergänzung.  Kommt andersherum auch vor — per Vorname zu sein, aber dennoch per Sie?

@gerrit Yes, it does, to the extent that it has its own name: Hamburger Sie. Encountered in the wild during my teenage years in various part time jobs.

@gerrit: Nein, dass man jemanden mit Vornamen anspricht, mit dem man per Sie ist, kommt eigentlich nie vor. Allenfalls kann ich mir das bei Künstlern vorstellen, die nur unter ihrem Vornamen bzw. ihrem Kosenamen bekannt sind. Beispiel: Ein Society-Reporter berichtet von einer Charity-Veranstaltung. Er sieht dort zwei Promis miteinander plaudern, geht zu den beiden und spricht sie an: »Schönen ...

... Abend, Nena und Heino! Werden Sie beide irgend wann mal ein Duett miteinander singen?« (»Nena« ist zwar nicht der Vorname der Sängerin Gabriele Susanne Kerner, sondern ihr Kosename, aber eben trotzdem ein Name, mit dem man das Du-Wort verbindet. Bei Heino (Heinz Georg Kramm) ist es ähnlich, bei ihm ist der Kosename aber direkt von seinem Vornamen abgeleitet.)

@HubertSchölnast: Selbstverständlich kommt das vor - und zwar in jedem Wiener Kaffeehaus, wo der Ober nicht mit "Du", sondern mit "Sie" angesprochen wird, dennoch aber mit dem Vornamen tituliert: "Sie, Herr Franz, bringen's mir noch einen kleinen Schwarzen."

Ich mein, Du würdest in keinem der Fälle "Mein Chef, Herr Krainer" schreiben, sondern entweder, oder. Richtig und wichtig ist, dass Sprecher und Hörer unterschiedliche Wissensstände haben können, was Vor- und Nachname der Person ist und das drittens eine Funktion (mein Chef/Chauffeur/Bruder) hereinspielen kann und dass Namen aus dem Kontext mehr oder weniger eindeutig sein können oder nicht, auch mit asymmetrischem Wissensstand zwischen Sprecher und Hörer. Ich schätze meist steht die einfache, sichere Identifizierung um wen es geht im Vordergrund. Die Komplexität nimmt noch zu, …

…, wenn es weitere nicht direkt Angesprochene gibt, die mit zuhören, und denen gegenüber man Transparenz herstellen will, dann wäre auch "Mein Chef, Herr Krainer ..." eine geschmeidige Lösung. Frau Kastner weiß zwar, dass Hr. Krainer Dein Chef ist, aber Herr Bodelwickel, der dabei steht, und auch eingeladen ist, wahrscheinlich nicht.

Wenn ich jemandem gegenüber andere Personen erwähne, spielt es keine Rolle, in welchem Verhältnis ich zu diesen anderen Personen stehe und wie ich sie anrede.
Der Vater sagt zu dem Kind in der Regel nicht: "Ulrike kommt gleich, dann essen wir." Er wird statt dessen sagen: "Mama kommt gleich ..."
Genauso verhält es sich, wenn ich mit anderen Erwachsenen über Erwachsene spreche. Wenn ich mit dem Gesprächspartner per Sie bin, halte ich sowohl meine als auch seine persönlichen Verhältnisse außen vor. Ich würde dann immer von Frau X und Herrn Y sprechen.

Und wenn ich mit dem Gesprächspartner bei Du bin?

Dann weißt du in der Regel auch, wie die zwei miteinander reden und kannst es so halten wie in dem Beispiel mit dem Kind oder einfach nachfragen.

Das Beispiel mit "Mama" ist nicht hilfreich, denn "Mama" ist weder ein Vor-, noch ein Nachname. Es impliziert auch, dass der Sprecher das Verwandschaftsverhältnis von Adressat und Objekt kennt, entspräche also der Alternative "Birgit hat mir bereits geholfen" vs. "Ihre/Deine Chefin* hat mir bereits geholfen". (*Sekretärin, Mitbewohnerin, Schwester, ...). Dass man Beobachtungen über das Sprechen mit Kindern bruchlos auf Erwachsene übertragen kann ("genauso") erscheint mir auch gewagt - wieso greift man dann nicht auf Beispiele des Redens mit Erwachsenen zurück?

Frau Musterfrau würde ich nur dann mit ihrem Vornamen benennen, wenn wir alle drei miteinander per Du sind. In jedem anderen Fall mit "Frau Musterfrau".

Auch wenn Du mit Frau Musterfrau verheiratet oder eng verwandt wärst?

@userunknown Du hast recht. In so einem Fall würde ich Dritten gegenüber z.B. "meine Gattin B." oder "meine Tochter B." schreiben.

Die Frage, wie man jemand dritten gegenüber einem Gesprächspartner erwähnt, ist nicht so sehr vom eigenen Verhältnis zum Gesprächspartner, sondern vielmehr von dessen Verhältnis zum Erwähnten abhängig. Das heißt: wenn der A mit dem B über den C spricht, dann sollte er Cs Vornamen nur verwenden, wenn er sicher weiß, daß der B mit dem C per Du ist.
Im Zweifelsfalle - aber das ist weniger eine Frage der Sprache, sondern mehr eine des allgemeinen Benimms - sollte man da eher Vorsicht walten lassen und lieber die förmlichere Anrede wählen. Sollte der andere durchblicken lassen, daß er sehr wohl mit dem Erwähnten vertrauteren Umgang pflegt, so kann man immer noch in den informelleren Ton wechseln. Die andere Richtung ist mit deutlich mehr Peinlichkeiten verbunden.

Nein. Wenn ich zu den Hoppenstädts eingeladen werde, Herrn Theo Hoppenstädt kenne und mit ihm per Du bin, weiß, dass seine Gattin Christel heißt, aber mit dieser noch nie Kontakt hatte, und weiß, dass er nicht weiß, dass ich ihren Vornamen kenne, dann werde ich ihm gegenüber sicher nicht fragen "Mag Christel lieber Tulpen oder Rosen". Allerdings werde ich auch nicht fragen "Mag Frau Hoppenstädt ..." sondern "Mag Deine Frau ...".
